# Need simple explanation on squarefree integers and sum of squares.

Tags: number-theory

Just need an explanation of something brought in my number theory class for us to just look over.

Let $D$ be a positive squarefree, even integer.

$Q(D):=\#\{(B,C): D=B^2+C^2 \ \text{with} \ B,C\in \mathbf{\geq 1} \}$

Hint: Try to find $Q(D;Y)$ (below) and see if you can take the limit as $Y$ goes to infinity:

$Q(D;Y):=\#\{(B,C): D=B^2+C^2 \ \text{with} \ B,C\in \mathbf{\geq 1} \ \text{and} \ D \ \text{a pos. squarefree integer} \ < Y \}$

Also what happens if you ignore some conditions

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: @RobertIsrael 2nd part on the limit. I guess we are putting a bound on D?